# I updated python 3.9 in linux mint 20.3 by default and command line doesn't work, no taskbar

Tags: shell, linux-mint, python, command

Yesterday I installed Python3.9 in linuxmint-20.3 and I changed by default (before I had python3.8.3), and when I restarted the computer, I could't open the command line, there was no taskbar, and the windows didn't have the top bar.

I'm thinking of factory reinstalling linux from USB, but I have a lot of programs and I don't want to lose them. What could I do to not lose them? Is there any solution? I know that the problem is with the python version, but now I cannot open the command line to delete this version of Python or to change it back to the original version. I have the files on other hard drives, so with that no problem (I hope I don't have any problems with changing the user in the reboot and lock them because they are from other user).

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use `apt` or compile it from source?

Comment: I used apt, and after that I changed the version using sudo update-alternatives --config python3

Comment: Changing the default python interpreter is often a recipe for disaster - you didn't create a full backup before starting this, did you?

Comment: [It appears you're not the first to end up in this situation.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=350286)

Answer (score 1):

Python3 is used by your system OS and shouldn't be changed. Rather, it's better you create a symlink pointing to the latest version if you don't want the stress of typing the name and version to access it. Boot into recovery mode, and change your python3 version back to it's default from the root terminal. The below command should work

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8.3
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```